# Pull from multiple tables in my login script

Tags: php

As of: June 4 2013, 7:37 pm CST we have no solution for this problem.

I have a script that logs my users in and pulls from information from a database table. Right now it pulls from one table `affiliate_information` and gets multiple items.

I am wanting it to pull from `affiliate_information` AND `affiliate_tasks` Right now I simply added the following right above the `$_SESSION['company_name'] = $row['company_name'];` and added the required code to my page to echo it but nothing is happening.

```
//pull from another table in the database 
                        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `affiliate_tasks` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");

                        $_SESSION['task_name'] = $row['task_name'];
                        $_SESSION['due_date'] = $row['due_date'];
                        $_SESSION['status'] = $row['status'];
```

This is the full script:

```
<?php

include "scripts/user_managment/connect.php";


    //If the user has submitted the form
    if($_POST['submit']){
        //protect the posted value then store them to variables
        $username = protect($_POST['username']);
        $password = protect($_POST['password']);

        //Check if the username or password boxes were not filled in
        if(!$username || !$password){
            //if not display an error message
            echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.green-panda.com/website/panda/affiliates/login.php?msg=' . urlencode(base64_encode('A username and password is required!')) . '">';
        }else{
            //if the were continue checking

            //select all rows from the table where the username matches the one entered by the user
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `affiliate_information` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
            $num = mysql_num_rows($res);

            //check if there was not a match
            if($num == 0){
                //if not display an error message
                echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.green-panda.com/website/panda/affiliates/login.php?msg=' . urlencode(base64_encode('The username and/or password does not match!')) . '">';
            }else{
                //if there was a match continue checking

                //select all rows where the username and password match the ones submitted by the user
                $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `affiliate_information` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'");
                $num = mysql_num_rows($res);

                //check if there was not a match
                if($num == 0){
                    //if not display error message
                    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.green-panda.com/website/panda/affiliates/login.php?msg=' . urlencode(base64_encode('The username and/or password does not match!')) . '">';
                }else{
                    //if there was continue checking

                    //split all fields fom the correct row into an associative array
                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

                    //check to see if the user has not activated their account yet
                    if($row['active'] != 1){
                        //if not display error message
                        echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.green-panda.com/website/panda/affiliates/login.php?msg=' . urlencode(base64_encode('You have not yet activated your account!')) . '">';
                    }else{
                        //if they have log them in

                        //set the login session storing there id - we use this to see if they are logged in or not
                        $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];

                        //pull from another table in the database 
                        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `affiliate_tasks` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");

                        $_SESSION['task_name'] = $row['task_name'];
                        $_SESSION['due_date'] = $row['due_date'];
                        $_SESSION['status'] = $row['status'];

                        //get the users informaiton
                        $_SESSION['company_name'] = $row['company_name']; //get the company name 
                        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
                        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
                        $_SESSION['email_address'] = $row['email_address'];
                        $_SESSION['check_payable_to'] = $row['check_payable_to'];
                        $_SESSION['add_line_1'] = $row['add_line_1'];
                        $_SESSION['add_line_2'] = $row['add_line_2'];
                        $_SESSION['city'] = $row['city'];
                        $_SESSION['state'] = $row['state'];
                        $_SESSION['zip'] = $row['zip'];
                        $_SESSION['main_phone'] = $row['main_phone'];
                        $_SESSION['mobile_phone'] = $row['mobile_phone'];
                        $_SESSION['affiliate_since_date'] = $row['affiliate_since_date'];
                        $_SESSION['direct_deposit'] = $row['direct_deposit'];
                        $_SESSION['paper_check'] = $row['paper_check'];
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];  //gets the username
                        $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password']; //get the password
                        $_SESSION['profile_pic_src'] = $row['profile_pic_src']; //gets the profile pic
                        $_SESSION['website_url'] = $row['website_url']; //gets the website
                        $_SESSION['account_balance'] = $row['account_balance']; 
                        $_SESSION['domain_count'] = $row['domain_count'];
                        $_SESSION['earning_count'] = $row['earning_count'];
                        $_SESSION['received_count'] = $row['received_count'];
                        $_SESSION['referrals_count'] = $row['referrals_count'];

                        //update the online field to 50 seconds into the future
                        $time = date('U')+50;
                        mysql_query("UPDATE `affiliate_information` SET `online` = '".$time."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");

                        //redirect them to the affiliate_informationonline page
                        echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.green-panda.com/website/panda/affiliates/index.php?msg=' . urlencode(base64_encode('You have successfully logged in!')) . '">';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

How can I make it so this script pulls from `affiliate_information` and `` `affiliate_tasks `` and possibly even more tables? Or do I need to do this in a separate script? If so, how would I make it get the information at the same time.

In my regular page I have `<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION[task_name]; ?>` to be able to echo the variables.

Comment: If you're coding something from scratch these days, try using PDO or mysqli. way easier to work with in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `affiliate_tasks` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");

                    $_SESSION['task_name'] = $row['task_name'];
```

Your not actually doing anything with `$res` to turn it into `$row`

inserting

```
$row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

between the 2 lines should fix it.
if not there is a problem with the SQL

Also avoid uing mysql_*, instead use PDO or mysqli_*

update:

Give this a go

```
           $aff_tasks = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `affiliate_tasks` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
          $row_tasks =  mysql_fetch_assoc($aff_tasks);
                        $_SESSION['task_name'] = $row_tasks['task_name'];
                        $_SESSION['due_date'] = $row_tasks['due_date'];
                        $_SESSION['status'] = $row_tasks['status'];
```

Comment: yes, adding that will return the rows from the database not just the identifier to the query

Comment: Where do I need to insert `$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);`

Comment: This results in absolutely nothing being pulled from the database into my page. including the regular stuff that was already there before.

Comment: I'm using GoDaddy I don't see that in my files

Comment: Nevermind I found the error logs in my control panel. But it doesn't seem like anything is there. I'll try it

Comment: Yeah I'm not getting anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31215/discussion-between-user2371301-and-user1281385)

Answer (score 0):

You should just join tables

```
SELECT *
FROM `affiliate_information` a_i
LEFT JOIN `affiliate_tasks` a_t ON a_i.`username` = a_t.`username`
WHERE a_i.`username` = 'SomeUsername'
```

Comment: eddited @user2371301 left join was missing

Comment: This is what it gives me: 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/38/10473938/html/website/panda/affiliates/scripts/user_managment/login.php on line 55'

Comment: @user2371301 To make things clear i eddited php out - sou  you have clean sql.